# Input JSON into mongodb without a file and without being connected to mongod?

Tags: json, mongodb, powershell

Is it possible to input a JSON doc into mongodb without connecting to the mongo shell and without saving the input into a file?

Situation, I have a powershell script that has JSON data in a variable. I'd like to just input that variable into mongo, maybe by calling the mongoimport command?

So far, I have tried:

```
mongoimport --db test --collection test1 {"field": "value"}
```

but it doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find no other way other than writing the variable to a file, and using mongoimport after that:

```
 $jsonOutput = $output | ConvertTo-Json
        Set-Content -Path "./info.json" -Encoding UTF8 -Value $jsonOutput


    <#####################################################################
                import into mongodb
    #####################################################################>

        mongoimport --host $mongohost --db $mongodbName --collection $collectionName ./$computername.json --jsonArray >$null
        Write-Host "file written to db"
        Remove-Item ./info.json
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  use mongoImport or mongorestore to  input the Json. just follow the link :  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

Comment: It looks like thats just for file.json though. what about a json doc in commandline? or would you just save the json to a temp doc, import it and delete the file?